# Create stacked relative change plot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, axis-labels

I am looking to create a plot in R that shows the relative change of some variables between two factors. I would like to stack them to reduce redundant text and make it easy to visually compare the changes between the two factors. I would like it to look something like this: http://postimg.org/image/clmw5zj37/.

where the lines (or bars) represent the relative change (y) in each variable (X), a solid circle (or any other symbol) represents no change, and an asterisk indicates the the change is statistically significant. Anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this in R?

Comment: After looking at that plot I cannot tell what you mean by "stack". You should also post some data.

Comment: By 'stacked' I am referring to arranging the two plots vertically, on top of each other. Any numerical data can be generated in R or you can use random numbers. The relative changes in my data are differences between medians = median(time2)-median(time1)/median(time1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?
[image]

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=toupper(letters[1:10]),
                 y=rnorm(20,0,50),
                 sig=sample(0:1,20,replace=T), 
                 factor=rep(c("Factor1","Factor2"),each=10))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),shape=1,size=3)+
  geom_linerange(aes(x=x,ymin=0,ymax=y))+
  geom_text(data=df[df$sig==1,], aes(x=x,y=y+10*sign(y)),label="*",size=10)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
  facet_grid(factor~.)
```

Note that it is considered polite to provide a representative dataset. See [this link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for the way to formulate a question well.

**Edit** In response to OP's comment.

To plot points only when`y=0`, set `data=df[df$y==0,]` in the call to `geom_point(...)`. Vertical alignment of the stars can be done using `vjust=` in the call to `geom_text(...)`. So, this code:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=toupper(letters[1:10]),
                 y=rnorm(20,0,50),
                 sig=sample(0:1,20,replace=T), 
                 factor=rep(c("Factor1","Factor2"),each=10)) 
df[sample(1:nrow(df),4),2:3]=0     # add some zeros to example

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(data=df[df$y==0,],aes(x=x,y=y),size=5)+
  geom_linerange(aes(x=x,ymin=0,ymax=y))+
  geom_text(data=df[df$sig==1,], aes(x=x,y=y+10*sign(y)), 
            label="*", size=10, vjust=+0.65)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
  facet_grid(factor~.)
```

Genreates this ggplot:
[image]

Comment: This works. However, I have two issues: when y is negative, the asterisk is closer to the point than if y>0 (presumably because of the order of operations at line 11, y=y+10*sign(y), but I am unsure?); secondly, in my original question I indicated that I wanted points only for x,y=0, how can the syntax be changed to support that?